# The Pros and Cons of the following two Codes

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

Code 1: (HTML and typescript)

I have this button event in HTML and do the disable check from the typescript.

```
<button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="onClickDelete()" [disabled]="checkStatus()">
  <mat-icon class="fa fa-trash"></mat-icon>
</button>
```

```
public checkStatus(): boolean {
    return this.status === 3 || this.status === 4;
}
```

Code 2: (Only HTML)

Doing the disable check directly in HTML

```
<button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="onClickDelete()" [disabled]="status === 3 || status === 4">
  <mat-icon class="fa fa-trash"></mat-icon>
</button>
```

My task is to increase the performance speed of the website so which way should I use to build a website or there are no differences between two of the codes?

Comment: The choice between these two is... a) not going to make a measurable impact on performance (prove me wrong by measuring them both)... b) not the right question - the right question is "which is more readable because I'll need to maintain this app"... c) a bit too subjective for Stack Overflow.